# Input datalist not working in dynamically added element

Tags: javascript, html, web, html-datalist

Let's say i have list input with datalist like this:

```
<input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="" list="colorlist" />
<datalist id="colorlist">
    <select style="display: none;">
        <option value="Black" />
        <option value="Blue" />
        <option value="Dark Green" />
        <option value="Grey" />
        <option value="Green" />
        <option value="Red" />
        <option value="White" />
        <option value="Yellow" />
    </select>
</datalist>
```

If list like this is loaded as a part of bigger HTML structure that i get via AJAX, this datalist does not work. No autocomplete list is shown. In any other cases, if this is load as default view (so without any AJAX request) everything is working fine. I'm 100% sure that every attribute has correct name.

What I'm missing?

Comment: Can you please give more info? How are you handling the response from AJAX? Can you create a plunker or jsfiddle

Comment: I'd imagine it's because the events associated with your autocomplete are bound when the page is loaded. So you'll need to either replicate that code when you load from ajax, or look in to [event delegation](https://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate).

Comment: @Vikash https://jsfiddle.net/vn6emshs/1/ this is example of my input with datalist, i copied it from my code (where it doesn't work) but somehow it worked on jsfiddle, strange...

Answer (score 0):

The datalist element is not correct. Remove the 'select'. In the jsfiddle you provided in your comment, you do not have the select.

So it should definitely work like that:

`<input type="text" name="color" id="color" value="" list="colorlist" />
    <datalist id="colorlist">
            <option value="Black" />
            <option value="Blue" />
            <option value="Dark Green" />
            <option value="Grey" />
            <option value="Green" />
            <option value="Red" />
            <option value="White" />
            <option value="Yellow" />
    </datalist>`